# pgadmin failing to connect to postgres host

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I just brought up a new machine running the latest Debian and PostgreSQL and pgadmin versions.  Everything was running fine, and I could connect to postgres using pgadmin and work in the database.

After rebooting the postgres machine today I can connect to and query postgres via ODBC but can no longer connect to the server via pgadmin.  I log in to pgadmin successfully, but when trying to connect to the server I get

> connection failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly

This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.*.

The log file `/var/log/pgadmin/pgadmin4.log` reports *The CSRF token is missing.*

I added the lines below to /usr/pgadmin4/web/config_local.py without impact:

```
 PGADMIN_CONFIG_ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION="False"<br>
 PGADMIN_CONFIG_WTF_CSRF_CHECK_DEFAULT: 'False'<br>
 PGADMIN_CONFIG_WTF_CSRF_ENABLED: 'False'
```

I'm not very experienced in this environment and am hoping someone can suggest a location to troubleshoot this before I muck up the configuration too much.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured this out - when I rebooted the postgres box for the first time since installing it received a new IP address from my router.  So I updated my home-grown DNS, AKA hosts files, on all my machines.

In the pgadmin configuration settings for the postgres host connection I used an IP address instead of the host name.  DOH!